# problems with comparing faces using the face recognition library, face to face comparison

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I wanted to compare faces in the line "matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(pessoas[c], original_face_encodings[b])" , if using the pessoas array works, if I use pessoas[c] to compare one at a time, I have the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "face.py", line 43, in <module>
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(pessoas[c], original_face_encodings[b])
File "C:\face-recognition\course\face_recognition\api.py", line 226, in compare_faces
    return list(face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check) <= tolerance)   
File "C:\face-recognition\course\face_recognition\api.py", line 75, in face_distance
    return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 2481, in norm
    return sqrt(add.reduce(s, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims)) numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

How can I solve it?

```
a = 110
pessoas = []
photos = []
b = 0
c = 0
r = 0
for i in range(100,a):   
    test_image = cv2.imread('test1/' + str(i) + '.jpeg')
    all_face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(test_image, model='CNN')
    original_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(test_image, all_face_locations)
    print(i)
    for b in range(len(all_face_locations)):
        if not pessoas:
            for r in range(len(all_face_locations)):
                pessoas.insert(r, original_face_encodings[r])
        else:
            for c in range(len(pessoas)):
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(pessoas[c], original_face_encodings[b])
                if(matches):
                    photos.insert(i, i) 
                else:
                    pessoas.insert(i, original_face_encodings[b]) 
print(pessoas)
print(photos)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that `pessoas[c]` array and `original_face_encodings[b]`  have the same shape. Currently, it seems that `pessoas[c]` has 1D shape and `original_face_encodings[b]` has 2D shape.

Try to wrap it in a list, for example:

```
pessoas.insert(r, [original_face_encodings[r]]) 

matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(pessoas[c], [original_face_encodings[b]]

pessoas.insert(i, [original_face_encodings[b]])
```